# How do I allow regular users to install printers?

Tags: printing, root, active-directory

I'm configuring a 10.10 machine for deployment in an organization with Likewise Open and Active Directory, and I need to know if Ubuntu can allow users to install printers automatically. I tested and it seemed that domain users have to manually enter their credentials to access a shared printer but also need root in order to install it. Is there a way around needing root to install printers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu

- system menu,

  - user and groups
  - dialog: Usersetting

    - button right: extended settings
    - Tab: userrights

There is an entry: configure printers. Maybe that is sufficient. Try it out. I didn't test it.

The names might differ, since I use xUbuntu, and the settings are de_DE, not en_US or en_SOMEWHERE - I translated myself.

Comment: Hmm, this works for regular users but there is no option for domain users when using Active Directory. I'll post another question asking about that.

Answer (score 1):

You must add them to the lpadmin group. For domain users that you don't want to add one at a time, you can map local groups like [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication#Assign_local_groups_to_users).